# Custom button not displaying in Today Extension

Tags: xcode, user-interface, uibutton, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I have some custom buttons in my host app that I'd like to use in the Today Extension.

They work just fine in the app but do not display in the widget.

The button on the left is my custom button class, the one on the right is a UIButton.  If I change it to my custom class it too disappears.

Any thoughts why this might be happening?

[image]

----------------------EDIT------------------------

Well, somehow I managed to get it to display but sometimes it's not drawing the whole button and sometimes it's drawing the button incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: How have you configured the button's appearance? Does it need an image to make it look that way?

Comment: @TomHarrington Nope.  It's just UIBezierPath's and the like.

Comment: I've tried to get images in there as well to no avail.

Comment: @TomHarrington I updated the post if you have a moment.  Thanks

Comment: @MayNotBe Do you solve this problem? Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002332/custom-figure-doesnt-display-in-today-extension

Comment: @Alexsander: nope sorry.  I'll follow your question and hope for a good answer

Comment: @MayNotBe I cannot even to display a circle in widget.