# Custom figure doesn't display in Today Extension

Tags: swift, swift2, today-extension

I make progress circle in today extension. I create additional class for it. I can see it in storyboard with help of `IBDesignable`. But circle doesn't appear in today extension on real device ( iPhone 5s, iPad 3) or simulator. How can I fix it?

```
    import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CPUView: UIView {

    // MARK: - colors
    @IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    @IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    @IBInspectable var thirdColor: UIColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        self.addCircle(10, capRadius: 0.0)
    }

    func addOval(lineWidth: CGFloat, path: CGPath, strokeColor: UIColor, fillColor: UIColor, strokeStart: CGFloat, strokeEnd: CGFloat) {
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shape.path = path
        shape.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor
        shape.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor
        shape.strokeStart = strokeStart
        shape.strokeEnd = strokeEnd
        layer.addSublayer(shape)
    }

    func addCircle(arcRadius: CGFloat, capRadius: CGFloat) {
        let X = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds)
        let Y = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)

        let firstPathCircle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(X - arcRadius/2, Y - arcRadius/2, arcRadius, arcRadius)).CGPath

        self.addOval(0.1, path: firstPathCircle, strokeColor: UIColor.redColor(), fillColor: UIColor.yellowColor(), strokeStart: 0.0, strokeEnd: 0.5)
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried to write the code in `drawRect` but I got the same result

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    let x = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds)
    let y = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)
    let radius = CGFloat()

    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(x - radius/2, y - radius, 100, 100)).CGPath

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = 0.0
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    shape.path = path
    layer.addSublayer(shape)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following code and it works for me

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200.0)
    }
```